# Converting string to date/hour at the 24hour mark: ValueError unconverted data remains: 4

Tags: python, date, type-conversion, extract, strptime

I am trying to extract the date and hour from the following string:

```
string = '3/24/2016 24'     # 24 is the hour
```

Using the following code:

```
result = datetime.strptime(string, '%m/%d/%Y %H')
```

However I am running into the following error message:
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4
Lead: Does strptime  not recognize 24 as an hour (0 -> 23 versus 1 -> 24)? And if so, how should I fix this since it's a string?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose to handle the corner case of 24, you can parse the date part as a date, then replace the "hour" mod 24, eg:

```
d, t = '3/24/2016 24'.partition(' ')[::2]
dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y').replace(hour=int(t) % 24)
# datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 24, 0, 0)
```